# Open Sans letter-spacing issue with Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: css, ubuntu, fonts

I have an issue with the letter-spacing in firefox on Ubuntu (Mint). I know that there are differences between browsers and how they render fonts, but I don't have this problem in Firefox on Windows (Nor do we have it on Chrome in Ubuntu).

Below is an example of the problem:

[Font difference over different browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdWB5.png)

Code of the "TV - AUDIO" header:

```css
body {
 font-family:             'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-size:               13px;
 -webkit-font-smoothing:  antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

h4.f_h4 {
 font-family:    'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size:      12px;
 font-weight:    bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor:         default;
}

ul.f_cats {
 font-family:     'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size:       11px;
 color:           #787878;
 padding-left:    0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

ul.f_cats > li {
 padding: 3px 0;
}

ul.f_cats > li > a {
 font-size:       11px;
 font-weight:     bold;
 color:           #787878;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 hcats">
  <h4 class="f_h4">TV - AUDIO</h4>
  <ul class="f_cats" id="cats1">
    <li><a href="#">TELEVISIE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AUDIO - HIFI</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DVD - BLU-RAY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">RADIO-CD-WEKKER-MP3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HOOFDTELEFOONS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

We tried the following:

- downloading the fonts instead of serving them from the google fonts
  api
- removing the font smoothing
- letter-spacing: 0
- font-kernel
- using reset.css

and probably some other things that I have forgotten by now.

Adding `letter-spacing: -1px;` is the only way I currently found to work around it but I feel like this is not a good solution. I'd like to know why this happens and if it can be solved in a more friendly manner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think we found the problem.

When including our fonts, we only had 300 and 400 weights enabled, like so:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

The other font-weights were probably rendered by the browser. Including more solved the problem.